# How to convince TypesSript you will return an Array with a property that is not null

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I am working with the following types:

```
type Fruits = {
    type: 'banana' | 'peach' | 'kiwi',
    price: null | string; 
}


type FruitsWithNonNull = Pick<Fruits, 'type'> & {
    price: NonNullable<Fruits['price']>
} 

const fruits:Fruits[] = [{type:'banana', price:null}, {type:'peach',  price:null},{type:'peach', price:'12'}]
```

```
const filteredFruits:FruitsWithNonNull[] = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.price !== null);
```

I get this error from `filteredFruits`:

```
Type 'Fruits[]' is not assignable to type 'FruitsWithNonNull[]'.
  Type 'Fruits' is not assignable to type 'FruitsWithNonNull'.
    Type 'Fruits' is not assignable to type '{ price: string; }'.
      Types of property 'price' are incompatible.
```

how can I convince typescript that when the filtering of the fruits is happening then the price is guaranteed to be there?

here is a link to the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAM5QLxQN4CgoFSiQBcUA5AEYCGAdndeVAD4WTUDGAFk6+QNZIA7knIAafITBwkHCGVoIANkpZRUwGbQDmAbii4AvrhPFo8ZGgDqKLgDkA9rTvLVWAAqz+AHgspUYhRm5AB8UABkOJIE0rLyUI7OrtSUShC+iP4A2uSxcuQAuiFGBrgcThpQAGaZaCR+aFkFmFBZ2GYkVAz04lB58ooqhoHt4PK5EJw8gX0yciSDSsOjpBNTvf0LroYFJuW0lVVISsAQcBAAJg2o9bWoNsD2Ti4qTS01lqgAdEcnZwAUHxQmDCQOAX36UAAhBgsIsAJS6IA)

I am not that confident with typescript yet so not sure what the solution is here.

Comment: Hello @brc-dd than you for your answer, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this than type casting it with `as`?

Comment: Filter returns you an array of the same type, use map instead or alternatively use explicit casting, but that I personally don't like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a user-defined type guard

```
type Fruits = {
    type: 'banana' | 'peach' | 'kiwi',
    price: null | string; 
}


type FruitsWithPrice = Pick<Fruits, 'type'> & {
    price: string;
}

const fruits: Fruits[] = [{type:'banana', price:null}, {type:'peach',  price:null},{type:'peach', price:'12'}];

const isFruitWithPrice = (x: any): x is FruitsWithPrice => {
    return x?.price !== null;
}

const filtered: FruitsWithPrice[] = fruits.filter(isFruitWithPrice)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=68&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAM5QLxQN4CgoFSiQBcUA5AEYCGAdndeVAD4WTUDGAFk6+QNZIA7knIAafITBwkHCGVoIANkpZRUwGbQDmAbii4AvrhPFo8ZGgDqKLgAUZczFDuz+AHgspUYimfIAfFAAZDiSBNKy8uqaSDq6RiYcAPa0GlAAZojeZF5oANoAus752GYkVAz04lCRciSKKoa+ZeDy5OzcNbWO8o1Kza2kHRCcPL517QCMAEzkhoUJuClpwFBIqHk2wPa9zgAUAB5kdCAAlGSH6+h5qNu7UZhBeIRQcBDACHC0UIcA-AA6SZQACEGCw-QSxmWqXSGSQSmAEHeABNctlrLYHFEis4spZUAD4YjkfsNlssb0zrggA)

Comment: Is it so that filter acts like a map, basically returning you an array of different type (different from input array) if you pass a typeguard as an iterator

Comment: @JSEvgeny kinda sorta. The purpose of the type guard is to narrow the type of fruit.price from string | null to just string. Under the hood it returns a boolean but at the type-system level it functions much like you suggest.

Comment: Omg that's way better than I was doing it :D I always felt like it should be something better than re-mapping (I hated it because of "unnecessarity"), so I would sometimes use explicit casting after filter, but that I don't like either, because casting, which in this case is kinda actually make sense. But I really like your solution with typeguard!